# List of list in Java

Tags: java, list

I'm very new to Java programming and I'm trying to take elements from a list and put them into a superlist as singleton lists:

`[object1,object2,object3] ---> [[object1][object2][object3]]`

How do I do this?

Comment: Show us what you have tried! If you don't know where to start I advise you to follow a Java tutorial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to create a list of lists, you can do something like:

```
List<List<Object>> list = new ArrayList<List<Object>>();
```

Where `Object` is the type of object you want to put in your list, for example a `String` object, then you'd just write:

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
```

If you wonder "How can I access the elements from the list inside the main list", then first you know to access the list inside your main list like:

```
List list2 = list.get(index);
```

Next you can use `list2` to access the elements of the list inside your main list like:

```
Object o = list2.get(index);
```

etc